# Remove zero after first two characters

Tags: sql, oracle

I have value like the below format,

```
150000005705
160000004559
```

I would like to remove three zeros after first two digits

I tried with this SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    '150000005705',
    REPLACE('150000005705', SUBSTR('150000005705', 3, 3)) new_num
FROM DUAL
```

Output should be like

```
150005705
160004559
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUBSTR twice and concatenate the strings

```
SELECT '150000005705',
   CONCAT(SUBSTR ('150000005705', 1, 2), SUBSTR ('150000005705', 6)) new_num
FROM DUAL
```

an alternative is to use replace if there are always 6 zero's

```
SELECT '150000005705',
   REPLACE ('150000005705', '000000', '000') new_num
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have the first approach.